# Date.toString(): How to prevent timezone name output in the PC locale in Chromium

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, electron, chromium

In our logs we are using Date.toString() to store events timestamps.
Example:

```
Wed Nov 21 2018 02:04:38 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

It is working well for us except when user's machine is in a locale other than English, then it would output timezone name in a local language (for example, Russian, Hebrew or Portugese)

```
Thu Nov 29 2018 16:21:07 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)
```

Is there a way to force toString() output to "EN-US" locale?

Comment: [Yes, there is.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: Does it always need to be "Pacific Standard Time"?

Comment: @SalmanA No, no need to be "Pacific Standard Time", just needs to be in English.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179/ Please make your life easier by using standard non-locale-specific format (iso 8601)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: English is a language, not a locale. The format of the string generated by *Date.prototype.toString* has been standardised since [*ECMAScript 2018*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) (the current version). The timezone name is optional and implementation dependent, it varies greatly across implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way:

```
var options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', timeZoneName: 'short' };
new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)
```

Output:

```
"Fri, Dec 14, 2018, 3:17:54 PM EST"
```

Comment: The output *toLocaleString* is not standardised, particularly the timezone name, which is the OP's issue.